# MPI_Bcast error on multiple nodes

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, mpi

Background: I am writing MPI versions of I/O system calls, which are based on the [collfs](http://github.com/ahmadia/collfs) project.

The code runs without error on multiple processors on a single node.

However, running on multiple nodes causes a segmentation fault... The error message with 2 processes, 1 process per node is the following:

```
$ qsub test.sub
$ cat test.e291810
0: pasc_open(./libSDL.so, 0, 0)
1: pasc_open(./libSDL.so, 0, 0)
1: mptr[0]=0 mptr[len-1]=0
1: MPI_Bcast(mptr=eed11000, len=435104, MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD)
0: mptr[0]=127 mptr[len-1]=0
0: MPI_Bcast(mptr=eeb11000, len=435104, MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD)
_pmiu_daemon(SIGCHLD): [NID 00632] [c3-0c0s14n0] [Sun May 18 13:10:30 2014] PE RANK 0 exit signal Segmentation fault
[NID 00632] 2014-05-18 13:10:30 Apid 8283706: initiated application termination
```

The function where the error occurs is the following:

```
static int nextfd = BASE_FD;
#define next_fd() (nextfd++)

int pasc_open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode)
{
    int rank;
    int err;

    if(!init)
        return ((pasc_open_fp) def.open)(pathname, flags, mode);

    if(MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank) != MPI_SUCCESS)
        return -1;
    dprintf("%d: %s(%s, %x, %x)\n", rank, __FUNCTION__, pathname, flags, mode);

    /* Handle just read-only access for now. */
    if(flags == O_RDONLY || flags == (O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC)) {
        int fd, len, xlen, mptr_is_null;
        void *mptr;
        struct mpi_buf { int len, en; } buf;
        struct file_entry *file;

        if(rank == 0) {
            len = -1;
            fd = ((pasc_open_fp) def.open)(pathname, flags, mode);
            /* Call stat to get file size and check for errors */
            if(fd >= 0) {
                struct stat st;
                if(fstat(fd, &st) >= 0)
                    len = st.st_size;
                else
                    ((pasc_close_fp) def.close)(fd);
            }
            /* Record them */
            buf.len = len;
            buf.en = errno;
        }
        /* Propagate file size and errno */
        if(MPI_Bcast(&buf, 2, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) != MPI_SUCCESS)
            return -1;
        len = buf.len;
        if(len < 0) {
            dprintf("error opening file, len < 0");
            return -1;
        }
        /* Get the page-aligned size */
        xlen = page_extend(len);
        /* `mmap` the file into memory */
        if(rank == 0) {
            mptr = ((pasc_mmap_fp) def.mmap)(0, xlen, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE,
                    fd, 0);
        } else {
            fd = next_fd();
            mptr = ((pasc_mmap_fp) def.mmap)(0, xlen, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                    MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, fd, 0);
        }
        ((pasc_lseek_fp) def.lseek)(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
        /* Ensure success on all aux. processes */
        if(rank != 0)
            mptr_is_null = !mptr;
        MPI_Allreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE, &mptr_is_null, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_LAND,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        if(mptr_is_null) {
            if(mptr)
                ((pasc_munmap_fp) def.munmap)(mptr, xlen);
            dprintf("%d: error: mmap/malloc error\n", rank);
            return -1;
        }
        dprintf("%d: mptr[0]=%d mptr[len-1]=%d\n", rank, ((char*)mptr)[0], ((char*)mptr)[len-1]);
        /* Propagate file contents */
        dprintf("%d: MPI_Bcast(mptr=%x, len=%d, MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD)\n",
        rank, mptr, len);
        if(MPI_Bcast(mptr, len, MPI_BYTE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) != MPI_SUCCESS)
            return -1;
        if(rank != 0)
            fd = next_fd();
        /* Register the file in the linked list */
        file = malloc(sizeof(struct file_entry));
        file->fd = fd;
        file->refcnt = 1;
        strncpy(file->fn, pathname, PASC_FNMAX);
        file->mptr = mptr;
        file->len = len;
        file->xlen = xlen;
        file->offset = 0;
        /* Reverse stack */
        file->next = open_files;
        open_files = file;
        return fd;

    }
    /* Fall back to independent access */
    return ((pasc_open_fp) def.open)(pathname, flags, mode);
}
```

The error occurs at the final `MPI_Bcast` call. I am at a loss as to why it is happening: the memory it copies from and to I can dereference just fine.

I am using MPICH on a custom Cray XC30 machine running SUSE Linux x86_64.

Thanks!

---

EDIT: I have tried replacing the `MPI_Bcast` call with a `MPI_Send`/`MPI_Recv` pair, and the result is the same.

Comment: Is it possible that you end up in a race condition when calling `fd=next_fd()` in other processes?

Comment: I don't think so, since `fd`'s are thread dependent, and `next_fd` is defined as a simple increment of a global.

Comment: Once the processes have spawned, the global variable is the same in each process (having its own unique memory there, everything is copied over!). If you increment it and do not communicate it to all other process, each process but rank 0 will have the same fd, (of course the memory of fd is process unique).

Comment: The file descriptors are incremented and maintained separately for each thread -- hopefully the edit I made to the code cleared that up.

So rank 0 will have the "real" `fd` returned by the actual syscall, while the others will have a `fd` I have generated. Since the `fd`'s are thread-specific, and the syscalls manipulating file descriptors are all overridden, would it still be a problem?

Comment: What happens if you copy mmaped data (mptr) to a `malloc`ed buffer, do you still get a segfault?

Comment: ooc, are there any compiler warnings `-Wall -Wextra` which indicate something?

Comment: @Anycorn I tried that today, and it worked. If you are willing to write up an answer, with perhaps some ideas why it works, I will assign you the bounty!

Comment: @TimKelsall It is probably something peculiar to MPI implementation - I don't have a specific answer, just a conjecture, if you would like that as an answer, I will surely accept the bounty.

Comment: Could you try replacing `xlen` with `len` in the call to `mmap` - there is no requirement that the mapping length should be an integer multiple of the page size. With `len` equal to 435104, you are mapping 3168 bytes more than the actual file size. It is possible that this makes the Aries driver unhappy.

Comment: @Hristo Unfortunately I still get a segmentation fault when doing that.

Comment: May be you should try reaching Cray through the support channel of the organisation that hosts the machine.

Comment: @Hristo Will do! This is on ARCHER (UK), FWIW.

Comment: You could try to register the buffer with uGNI explicitly. Check the error code to see if/why it fails. That may tell you why MPI can't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cray MPI implementation probably does some magic for performance reasons.  Without knowing the internals much of the answer is a guess.

The inter-node communication likely does not utilize the network stack, relying on some sort of shared memory communication.  When you try to send `mmap`-ed buffer over the network stack something somewhere breaks - the DMA engine (I'm wildly guessing here) cannot handle this case.

You can try to page lock the mmaped buffer - perhaps `mlock` will work just fine.
If that fails, then go with copying the data into `malloc`ed buffer.

Comment: `mlock` does not work sadly -- I'm having to use the `malloc`/`memcpy` solution for now.

Comment: Cray uGNI might not be able to RDMA such buffers in which case it _should_ do the copy internally, but since it doesn't, your workaround of doing so explicitly is correct.

Comment: @Anycorn inter-node is a typo. You meant intranode bypasses network stack.